# Custom Sorting of Solr Facet Values - Rails & Sunspot Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, sunspot, sunspot-rails, facet

I am using Sunspot Solr to drilldown with faceted searching.  However I am having an issue when trying to display the facet values sorted in the order they need to be.  My products could have sizes that are either (S, M, L, XL, XXL) and some products have sizes ranging such as shoe sizes (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13).  When setting the facet.sort method to 'index' it puts the string values into alphabetical order, which results in [L, M, S, XL, XXL] and [10, 11, 12, 8, 9] respectively.  What would be a good method for achieving a custom sort method to achieve these goals?

My Contoller:

```
@search = Product.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    facet(:size, :sort => :index)
    with(:size, params[:size]) if params[:size].present?
end
```

My View:

```
<% for row in @search.facet(:brand).rows %>
    <li>
        <% if params[:brand].blank? %>
            <%= link_to link_to "#{row.value} (#{row.count})", params.merge({:brand => row.value}) %>
        <% else %>
            <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", params.merge({:brand => nil}) %>)
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

The Resulted Sort That Is Displayed

```
   SIZE 
L (10)
M (10)
S (10)
XL (10)
XXL (10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, Solr only accepts two sort values for facets, count (number of results) and index (lexicographic). Assuming you don't want to change the indexed data, you have two alternatives, sort the facets array manually, or create a custom query facet. I would opt for the former, as you have a very limited facet result set.

**Manual sort**

```
# supposing these are your possible sizes
SCALE = %w(S M L XL XXL) 
# once you perform your search sort based on the scale order
@search.facet(:size).rows.sort_by! { |r| SCALE.index(r.value) }
```

**Query facet**

```
@search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  facet(:size) do
    row('S') { with(:size, 'S') }
    row('M') { with(:size, 'M') }
    row('L') { with(:size, 'L') }
    row('XL') { with(:size, 'XL') }
    row('XXL') { with(:size, 'XXL') }
  end
  with(:size, params[:size]) if params[:size].present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great!  I opted for the Query facet approach as I could not get the manual sort working properly (error - comparison of NilClass with 2 failed).  I'd +1 you here but as I am new to stack overflow it wont allow me yet.

Comment: My guess is some products wouldn't have a size so the index would be null and the comparison would fail. But glad to hear the other alternative worked.